# how to store value of select_tag in javascript var?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to store the value of  the select from a form into my javascript.

This works:

```html
<div id="tshirt-div">
    ....
</div>
<select id="tshirt-color">
   <option value="#fff">White</option>
   <option value="#000">Black</option>
   <option value="#f00">Red</option>
   <option value="#008000">Green</option>
   <option value="#ff0">Yellow</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById("tshirt-color").addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("tshirt-div").style.backgroundColor = this.value;
}, false);
</script>
```

I am trying to do this:

```erb
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :color_id, @items.order(:title), :colors, :title, :id, :title, include_blank: "Select Color", id: "tshirt-color" %>
<script>
document.getElementById("tshirt-color").addEventListener("change", function(){
   var bg_color = this.value
   document.getElementById("tshirt-div").style.backgroundColor = <%= Color.find(bg_color) %>;
}, false);
</script>
```

A few of my attempts:

```js
var bg_color = document.getElementById("tshirt-color").value
```

inside and outside of the function

```js
var bg_color = document.getElementById("tshirt-color").addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("tshirt-div").style.backgroundColor = <%= Color.find(bg_color.value) %>;
, false);
```

I have tried storing the `var` many different ways but each gives me the following error:

> undefined local method or variable 'bg_color'

The value of the `f.grouped_collection_select` is an integer so I want to then find the color title (red, blue, green, etc.) and return that to the `...style.backgroundColor`.

How can I store the select from the form, store it as a variable, and then find the color from the Color model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access JavaScript variables from inside the ERB tags. ERB lies on top of the script. Meaning that when the page request is made to the Rails server it will compile the page so that the ERB is interpreted. Then a plain JavaScript file or HTML file is send to the client. The JavaScript will be executed on the client.

```
<%= Color.find(bg_color) %>
```

Is run on the server side and has no access to the JavaScript variable `bg_color`.

A simple solution is to provide all the colors up front and pick the color from that.

```js
const colors = <%= Color.pluck(:id, :value).to_h.to_json.html_safe %>;

document.getElementById("tshirt-color").addEventListener("change", function(){
  document.getElementById("tshirt-div").style.backgroundColor = colors[this.value];
}, false);
```

If you don't want to provide all colors up front you'll have to set-up an AJAX request that queries the server when selecting a color.

---

Let me quickly explain `<%= Color.pluck(:id, :value).to_h.to_json.html_safe %>`.

```
tmp = Color.pluck(:id, :value) # retrieve the id and value of the colors
#=> [[1, "#fff"], [2, "#000"]]
tmp = tmp.to_h # convert the nested array into a hash
#=> { 1 => "#fff", 2 => "#000" }
tmp = tmp.to_json # convert the hash to a JSON string
#=> '{"1":"#fff", "2":"#000"}'
tmp = tmp.html_safe # mark the string as HTML safe so ERB won't replace characters such as " with &quot;
#=> '{"1":"#fff", "2":"#000"}'
```

Since JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation it can simply be read by read as part of JavaScript.

---

Alternatively you could manually build the options, and provide the color value through a custom attribute. An option could for example look something like this:

```html
<option value="1" data-color-value="#fff">White</option>
```

Then use the additional attribute to set the color.

```js
const color = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.colorValue;
document.getElementById("tshirt-div").style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: Thanks but this is giving me an error in the javascript due to the ruby: `Unexpected token &` ... Assuming this is due to pluck but what do you think: `const colors = {&quot;1&quot;:&quot;White&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Black&quot;,&quot;3&quot;:&quot;Blue&quot;,&quot;4&quot;:&quot;Red&quot;};`

Comment: @uno Seems like ERB replaces the HTML unsafe characters. Add `.html_safe` add the and to mark the string as HTML secure. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Just had to use `var` instead of `const` because my javascript is looped onto multiple canvas's

Answer (score 1):

You could always just store the value in a [hidden field](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag) element and just update the value of it whenever the select changes.

Then do something like

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'color_id', '0', onchange: "changeColor()", id: 'selected-color-field'%>
<script>
  function changeColor() {
    var selectedColor = document.getElementById("selected-color-field").value
    // Do whatever
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How does this work exactly? if the grouped_collection_select is being changed into the hidden field, doesn't that also need some sort of `onchange` as well?

Comment: I am just confused on how exactly the `grouped_collection_select` value is being passed to the hidden field here

Comment: @uno you'd do it with jquery. Just attach a simple `$('#selected-color-field').val(event.target.value)` to the select change.